# (Granger) Causality in a VAR model with insignificant lags removed

Tags: model-selection, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I am interested in a **VAR** model to analyze the relationship of consumer confidence (CC) and GDP growth by testing for **contemporaneous effects** and for **Granger Causality** as a first step.

I started with a VAR(5) and jointly removed insignificant lags so both CC and GDP are explained by the first 2 lags of CC and lags 1,4,5 from GDP. Doing so is approved by a wald test and improves my model in terms of the AIC, but the results for contemporaneous effects and for Granger Causality change completely. In the reduced VAR there is no significant correlation in the residuals and Granger Causality in both directions. In the full VAR(5) there is significant correlation in the residuals and Granger Causality only from CC to GDP.

Therefore my **question(s)**:

1. Is it valid to remove insignificant lags from the VAR(5) model before testing for Granger causality?
2. What are general arguments for working with the full VAR model or working with the reduced VAR?